# how to change recordes that are not connected via lookup?

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I need your help, how do I connect two fields that are not linked to each other using a common field eg a contact address field with an address field in the object I have created using common info like account id.
Is there a way to do this without using code in tools like the process builder?
I would really appreciate your help and Your wisdom

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object that operates like a junction object.  The way you would do this, is to have the junction object to connect un-related fields from un-related objects, using a common denominator Lookup object field. You could then create a formula that references the object's field of interest in your junction object, and then reference that formula in your other un-related object, if it in turn has a lookup field to that junction object.  It would look a bit like this:

Object1

Field: fieldYouWant

JunctionObject

Lookup Field: Object1

Formula Field (named: obj1FieldYouWant): Object1.fieldYouWant

Object2

Lookup Field: JunctionObject

Formula Field: JunctionObject.obj1FieldYouWant

The result would be the value of fieldYouWant on the Object2

Hope this helps

Comment: I want the field of the account number to be searchable, meaning that when I change the value in one of the fields in the first object, the second object will be found by the same account number.if I changed the email in the first object,The second object will be searched for whether there is also the same account number if true The email in the other object will be changed as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but I'll assume that what you need are formula fields.

Given that you have two objects, A__c and B__c, if you create a lookup field in A__c to B__c, you may then create as many formula fields as you wish in A__c to show B__c's fields. For example:

> B__r.BillingCity